# Reading and writing to file using fseek, wrong data on read

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

What I'm essentially trying to do is to create a 2D array but one that is in a file rather than in main memory.

In order to jump around this file i'm using fseek then fread to return what I need into the structures i'm using, the problem being that when I read from the file in `loadTile()` the structure `gameTile8File gtf` is full of what appears to be junk data.

Note that between the write and the read the file is never closed or flushed, don't think that should make a difference. The file is binary and always opened with options `"r+b"`.

I'm checking the return values on `fseek()`, `fread()` and `fwrite()` and all are saying there isn't a problem.

```
void saveTile(gameTile8& gt, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, bool newFile)
{
    //the given coordinates are in world space
    //first load the old coordinates (needed so that correct movements in file 2 are made)
    if(fseek(file1, (y * worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX) + x, SEEK_SET))
    {
        cout << "fseek failed! 01\n";
    }
    gameTile8File gtf;
    fread(&gtf, sizeof(gameTile8File), 1, file1);

    //convert a gameTile8 to a gameTile8File
    gtf.save(gt, file2, newFile);

    //once all movements are done then save the tile
    if(fseek(file1, (y * worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX) + x, SEEK_SET))
    {
        cout << "fseek failed! 01\n";
    }
    if(fwrite(&gtf, sizeof(gameTile8File), 1, file1) != 1)
    {
        cout << "fwrite failed! 01\n";
    }
}

void loadTile(gameTile8& gt, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    //the given coordinates are in world space
    //seek to the given spot load it
    if(fseek(file1, (y * worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX) + x, SEEK_SET))
    {
        cout << "fseek failed! 01\n";
    }

    gameTile8File gtf;
    //read in the tile
    if(fread(&gtf, sizeof(gameTile8File), 1, file1) != 1)
    {
        cout << "read failed! 01\n";
    }
    //then load it
    gtf.load(gt, file1, file2);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show how you called `saveTile()` and `loadTile()`.

Comment: Also, why do you `fread` in `saveTile`? It would probably help to see `gameTile8File::save` and `gameTile8File::load` as well.

Comment: The functions fseek, fread and fwrite are C functions, so the same would apply. As for why to read in a save function, because saveTile modifies the gameTile8File or more specifically the line gtf.save(gt, file2, newFile); converts from the gameTile8 to the gameTile8File in the save, for this the gameTile8File must be read in before modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `fseek()` takes an offset in bytes. You need to multiply your offset by the `sizeof(gameTile8File)`:

```
fseek(file1, sizeof(gameTile8File)*(y * worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX + x), SEEK_SET))
```

I'm not clear on your use of `worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX`. Is the grid you're storing in the file `worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX` tiles wide?

Comment: Yes that is it, thanks, it is now working. Yes the grid that i'm storing is worldTileKey::gameWorldSizeX*worldTile::worldTileCountX tiles wide.